# What is the meaning of 'iw' language code from firebase-ml-languageIdentifier? (flutter)

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-mlkit, firebase-machine-learning

I'm trying to use the firebase ML language identifier. Whenever I type something in Hebrew, I get back the language code 'iw' instead of 'he'. I tried to look for the API or the meaning of the 'iw' code in the documentation, but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

"iw" is an old code which was changed to "he" in 1989.

see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes

Answer (score 0):

We made some changes to Firebase ML Kit to better distinguish the on-device APIs from cloud based APIs. "ML Kit"(without firebase branding) contains all the on-device APIs. [Here's](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/migration) the migration guide from firebase mlkit to mlkit.

In the standalone mlkit, we are using he instead of iw for Hebrew.